# duda configurando sass en webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

estoy configurando webpack por primera vez y quiero incluir sass , por ende ya instale todos los loaders ,  la pregunta seria puedo unificar los "test" y los "use" o tengo que colocarlos por separado o sea uno para cada uno(uno para css , uno para ,sass, uno para style)?

{
test: /.svg$/,
use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
},

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ],
        },

        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                'css-loader'
            ],
        },

        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ],
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir todos los loaders en una misma regla. En función del resultado del patrón aplicará un loader u otro.

Los loaders se ejecutan de [derecha-izquierda](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#using-loaders). Y la salida de un loader es la entrada del siguiente. Así es como funcionan los loaders en webpack.

> Loaders are evaluated/executed from right to left (or from bottom to top). In the example below execution starts with sass-loader, continues with css-loader and finally ends with style-loader. See "Loader Features" for more information about loaders order.

Orden de ejecución.

`sass-loader` -> `css-loader` -> `style-loader` (añade el css generado al `head` en la etiqueta `<style`) -> `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` (extrae el css generado en un archivo separado).

```
{
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader',
    ],
},
```